# Hangfire Recurrent Job runs 7 times on trigger

Tags: c#, cronexpression, hangfire

My recurring job bills my clients on a set date using cronexpr. What happens is that it triggers and bills the client account 7 times on each occasion. I do not know what is happening. I have this pseudo code MVC 5  and C# below

```
  public static void AutomaticPayDo(int id)
    {
   var auto = db.AutomaticPayments.Where(i => i.DDPayId == id).ToList();

       for (var i = 0; i < auto.Count; i++)
               {
      Create invoices
               }
   process payment
    if (successful)
    {
     update invoice/s as paid
     send email to client
    }
    }
```

The cron reads in dashboard: At 06:00 PM, on day 24 of the month
Dashboard  states 40 workers and the live server is a Quad Core

Comment: Is it because of any error occurred in your process and hangfire retried it?
Please check your default retry count of hangfire added as 7.

Comment: I have set  GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });  but still having this issue